# 6-to-4 pin power adapter · Red wire connected on black wire?

Tags: power-supply, adapter

I just bought an nVidia GeForce GTX 550 Ti, which requires a 6 pin power connector, which my PSU doesn't have. However, it came with a 6-to-4 pin adapter. But when I connected the 4 pin connectors, this happened:

[image]

The red wire (5 V) from the adapter's connector is connected on the black wire (0 V) on the PSU's connector. Is this right?

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me, there's no way that you can put in a molex adapter backwards without breaking it and/or knowing that you dun goofed.

Comment: Just to clarify: Is there only a single 4-pin connector attached? Please add a photo of the whole adapter, if possible.

Comment: No, two 4 pin. Photo will come soon.

Comment: Here's the photo:
http://s11.postimg.org/rkwj20jpv/2014_07_01_14_07_00.jpg
slow_excellence said it's okay, but I find it really weird. So, the GPU doesn't need 5 V from that connector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [6-pin PCI-E connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI-E#Power) on your graphic card has the following pinout

```
   #
 -----
|o o o|
|+   +|
 -----
```

where `o` is GND and `+` is +12V, see e.g. http://www.techpowerup.com/articles/overclocking/psu/116

So, no 5V line is necessary and your adapter is fine.

Check out this adapter, where the manufacturer used sensible wire colors:

[image]

Comment: I imagined that that red couldn't be right. Thanks!